# int cannot be converted into int[][] error for 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Hi I am creating a program that generates magic squares using 2D arrays. In this method I am supposed initialize the variable size to num and establish the 2D array ms which was created outside the method. I am getting an error that says int cannot be converted into int[][]. Can someone help me?

```
class MagicSquare
{
    private int size;
    private int[][] ms;
    public MagicSquare(int num) // initialize size to num and establishes ms
    {
        num = size;
        ms = ms[num][num];
    }
```

Comment: I think you also meant to have `size = num;`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the array correctly
This is how you would do it

```
ms = new int[num][num];
```

Answer (score 1):

An array in Java cannot be initialised like that, try:

```
public MagicSquare(int num) // initialize size to num and establishes ms
{
    num = size;
    ms = new int[num][num];
}
```